# What type of web service should I use for consumption by iOS/Android apps?

Tags: android, .net, ios, wcf

I have to write some web services to support some mobile apps (Android and iOS) that our company will be producing. Because we use Windows/IIS servers the services will be based on WCF/.NET 4. I'm wondering what format will be the easiest to use on the mobile end. I know there's JSON, SOAP, and others, I just don't know which has the best support within a mobile environment. Suggestions?

I intend to have a single set of WCF services which are consumed by both mobile platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the input and it generally follows what I found while researching. I would seem that JSON will be the easiest to work with and it also seems to have less network overhead than SOAP. I haven't done much on the Android side yet but I found something called JSON-Framework (https://github.com/stig/json-framework) which provides classes for parsing JSON data in Objective-C (strange that Apple didn't include JSON support in their Cocoa Touch framework).

Comment: I've found the [Google GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) works great with Android. You can find most of the popular JSON libraries for any language at [json.org](http://json.org/) - including Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my experience, working with JSON is the best way for iOS and Android.

The server... I would use Java (struts or similar).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using the .NET-platform on the server, WCF supports sending/receiving XML or JSON messages pretty easily using [`WebHttpBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx) and [WebServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webservicehostfactory.aspx) to build RESTful services.

For the client platforms - you just need an HTTP Client capable of sending JSON or XML formatted messages to a URL and retrieving a response. There are many libraries that will make this easier to manage, but it depends on the complexities involved in your service.

I would avoid SOAP, but you can easily support it using WCF by adding [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) and a [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx).

Comment: +1 for addressing both sides of the OP's question (server and client).

Answer (score 0):

I used the Slim framework (PHP) to serve JSON via RESTish URLs, and the GSON library to convert the data, it was pretty straight forward in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I use apache Camel CXF (web service) & to parse the data I use JAXB. 
note: about cxf http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

Comment: -1 How is this *at all* applicable in an iOS/Android + .NET scenario?